# FAQ: Valid topics, incident response

Tags: discussion, site-faq

Incident response isn't listed as a relevent topic on the [FAQ](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#questions), should we add it?

Answer (score 4):

It is now. Good call, so have updated.:-)